# Protractor E2E test to select date from date picker (send key's not worked)

Tags: e2e-testing

Protractor E2E test to select date from date picker (send key's not worked)

Html snippet

[image]

Comment: I suggest you copy the part of code which are not working to your post instead of do print screen and the image is quite blur.

Comment: Below threads might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860488/how-to-test-a-angular-js-date-picker-from-protractor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983218/selecting-angular-ui-date-picker-value-from-the-calendar-using-protractor

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask